# How to make changes to Enhance Rick Text column as mentioned in Body

Tags: 2013, html, rich-text, multiple-lines-of-text

We have enhanced Rick Text column in SharePoint 2013 List. When we enter any text in Edit Source, HTML code is generated.

Due to this our custom code is not working sometimes(when `<span>` tag is generated).

Can anyone please let me know how to stop generating the HTML code in Enhanced Rich Text(should not change from Enhanced to Plain Text radio button)?

--
Starts here

Code:
[image]
In the Above code if the Edit Source format is only in **div** tag then no error. If the Edit Source format is as given below:
[image]

Then the **properties()** in the code is triggered and goes to the Other CS file as given below.

[image]
[image]

After coming to this Cs file, the Highlighted line is showing error on debugging.
The error that we got is:
**System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiColumnValue.ParseMultiColumnValue(String fieldV**

Comment: Are you creating hyperlinks or something in your multiline rich text field?

Comment: No. Just adding text only

Comment: And you don't want to make it plain text field? is there any specific reason you don't want to change it to plain text?

Comment: Yes. Our clients asked not to change it. That was mentioned in the requirement

Comment: ok. What about the custom code you are using? can you add some details or your custom code to your question?

Comment: We have updated the code . Please have a look